# Laravel : orderBy date a pivot table

Tags: laravel

I have an issue with my queries and can't figure it out. 
I have two models :

User

```
public function episodes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Episode::class, 'user_episode_view', 'user_id', 'episode_id')
        ->withTimestamps()
        ->orderBy('user_episode_view.created_at', 'asc');;
}
```

Episode

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_episode_view', 'episode_id', 'user_id');
}
```

My pivot table has timestamps and I would like, in my view, to sort $user->episodes by created_at. My problem is that sometimes, a user has seen two or three episodes in the same day so I would like to show inline the three episodes view like this :

```
<h4>The created_at data to show the date</h4>
<p>Episode 1</p>
<p>Episode 2</p>
<p>Episode 3</p>

<h4>The other created_at data to show the date</h4>
<p>Episode 1</p>

<h4>Yet another created_at data to show the date</h4>
<p>Episode 1</p>
<p>Episode 2</p>
<p>Episode 3</p>
```

This is my controller code:

```
public function historique($id)
{
    $user = User::where('id', $id)
        ->with(['episodes' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        }])
        ->first();

    return view('front.profils.historiques', compact('user'));
}
```

In my blade view I have this :

```
<div class="index-tops">
    @foreach ($user->episodes as $episode)
        {{$episode->created_at}}
        <div class="wrap-tops mb-2">

            <a href="">{{$episode->name}} <br>Diffusé le : {{$episode->programmation->date}}</a>

            <br>
            {{$episode->created_at}}
        </div>

    @endforeach
</div>
```

I don't know if it's clear but it makes me crazy -_-'

Comment: I have this error when I try that : Call to undefined relationship [episodes] on model [App\Models\User].

Comment: @CornelRaiu Why would it be a `hasMany` rather than a `belongsToMany`?

Comment: Please can you add the code for your controller method.

Comment: The problem is that it's working, i have my episode but not sorted by date when i call {{$episode->created_at}}, it gives me the date of the episode and not the date of my pivot table

Comment: My controller : public function historique($id)
    {

        $user = User::where('id', $id)->with(['episodes' => function($query) {
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        }])->first();
        return view('front.profils.historiques', compact('user')); 
    }

Comment: @Rwd just asking to make sure that is what the OP needs. woke up recently, having my coffee and having a look around :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that you want to order the episodes by the pivot's created_at column.

```
$user = User::where('id', $id)
    ->with(['episodes' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('user_episode_view.created_at', 'desc');
    }])
    ->first();
```

As per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) (scroll down to **Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns**), if you want to **show** the `created_at` date for the 
pivot table you can use the `pivot` attribute:

```
$episode->pivot->created_at;
```

You will also need to add the `withTimestamps()` method to your relationship:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_episode_view', 'episode_id', 'user_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

```
<div class="index-tops">
    @foreach ($user->episodes as $episode)
        {{$episode->pivot->created_at}}
        ...
    @endforeach
</div>
```

---

If you're wanting to group your episodes by date you can use the [groupBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-groupby) method on the episodes collection (please note this is not the same as the `groupBy` method on the query builder).

Firstly, change your controller method to be:

```
public function historique($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    $episodes = $user->episodes()
        ->orderBy('user_episode_view.created_at', 'desc')
        ->get()
        ->groupBy(function ($episode) {
            return $episode->pivot->created_at->toString();
        });

    return view('front.profils.historiques', compact('user', 'episodes'));
}
```

Then change your blade view to be:

```
<div class="index-tops">
    @foreach ($episodes as $date => $group)

        <p>{{ $date }}</p>


        @foreach ($group as $episode)
           ...
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</div>
```

---

If you want to format `$date` differently then you can either change it in the `groupBy` method in your controller and use the `$date` variable as shown above e.g.:

```
->groupBy(function ($episode) {
    return $episode->pivot->created_at->format('jS F Y');
})
```

or you could get the first entry in your blade file and format that:

```
<div class="index-tops">
    @foreach ($episodes as $date => $group)

        <p>{{ $group->first()->created_at->format('jS F Y') }}</p>


        @foreach ($group as $episode)
           ...
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</div>
```

For more information on how you can format the dates you can refer to the [PHP date documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: I tried that but it gives me the $episode->created_at and not the $user->episodes->created_at

Comment: @Charlotte I didn't realise you also wanted to show that date as well as ordering by it. I have updated my answer to show you how you can do this.

Comment: Arf, it doesn't work :( I have no error but it doesn't show

Comment: @Charlotte I've just realised that you didn't add `withTimestamps()` in your `User` mode. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Oh my god, THANKS !! and juste one last thing, how in the blade view this time, can I not duplicate the created_at ? To show one date and after the episodes ans another date with the episodes attach etc...

Comment: @Charlotte As in you essentially want to **group** the episodes by date?

Comment: @Charlotte I have added this to my above answer as well.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not quiet sure how it works, if I want just one time the date ? Like have one date in a p tag for example and all the episodes with this date below and below another date with all the episodes associated... I don't know if I'm clear

Comment: @Charlotte I have updated my post. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Charlotte Glad I could help! :)